# How to create empty label by using “Charts”?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

Following is using “Charts” for swift 4.0 to show line chart. But the last label will not show normally , and i want to add empty label x-axis to fix this issue.

[image]

I try to add " " to chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter, but it doesn't add an x-axis.

following is my code:

```
x1 = [10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 16.0]
x2 = [20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26.0]
times = ["8:00"," ","9:00"," ","10:00"," ","11:00"," ","12:00"," ","13:00"," ","14:00"]

setChart()

func setChart(){

    let lineDefault = UIColor(red: 140.0/255.0, green: 234.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let data = LineChartData()
    var lineChartEntry1 = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<x1.count {
        lineChartEntry1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x1[i])))
    }
    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry1, label: "a")
    line1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    line1.drawValuesEnabled = false
    line1.lineWidth = 2
    line1.setColor(lineDefault)
    data.addDataSet(line1)
    if (x2.count > 0) {
        var lineChartEntry2 = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<x2.count {
            lineChartEntry2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(x2[i])))
        }
        let line2 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry2, label: "b")
        line2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        line2.drawValuesEnabled = false
        line2.lineWidth = 2
        line2.setColor(UIColor.yellow)
        data.addDataSet(line2)
    }

    let chartFormatter = LineChartFormatter(labels: times)
    let xAxis = XAxis()
    xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
    mapLineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter
    mapLineChartView.data = data


}

private class LineChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    var labels: [String] = []

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return labels[Int(value)]
    }

    init(labels: [String]) {
        super.init()
        self.labels = labels
    }
}
```

How to create empty label by using “Charts” for swift 4.0?

My Environment:

> Charts version: 3.1.1
>
> Xcode version:10.0
>
> Swift version:4.0

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_… what happens? Won't compile? Crashes? Unexpected result?

Comment: i will show like picture, but doesn't add an x-Axis

Comment: Please show the code you're using in the context (e.g. show the whole func)

Comment: Update the code!

Comment: Have you checked / asked here… https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues?q=is%3Aissue ? There are 2766 closed issues, so a good chance yours (or something similar) is in there.

Comment: i find the soultion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is same with [issue #2608](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2608)

```
x1 = [10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 16.0, 16.0]
x2 = [20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26.0, 26.0]
times = ["8:00"," ","9:00"," ","10:00"," ","11:00"," ","12:00"," ","13:00"," ","14:00"," "]
```

[image]